# How to resize popup component

Tags: java, swing, popup

How to resize popup component after invoke `show()` method?
This example is not work:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public MyFrame() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(400, 300);
        setLocation(400, 300);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                showPopup();
            }
        });
    }

    void showPopup() {
        JComponent popup = new JPanel();
        popup.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
        popup.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
        Popup p = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(this, popup, this.getLocationOnScreen().x, this.getLocationOnScreen().y);
        p.show();

        popup.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 80));
        popup.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    }
}
```

Size of the component `popup` does not change.

I found the solution, you must explicitly change size of the window of popup component.

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(popup).setSize(200, 80);
```

But this solution works only in case if popup component located in another window. And this is not what I need.

Comment: `popup.setPreferredSize(new Dimention(100, 40));` Instead of that, try putting components (with borders, padding etc.) into the panel to make it a suitable size.  Setting a preferred/max/min size is not something you should typically be doing.

Comment: Adding new components into popup panel has no effect. Size of the component popup does not change.

Comment: As an aside `popup.setPreferredSize(new Dimention(100, 40));`  - that would not compile.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Сorrected, now compiled.

Comment: *For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).*  (This time *emphatic* as you seem to have missed that important bit.)

Comment: Try invalidating the popup pane or find the root pane and invalidate it, use something like SwingUtilities#getRoot or SwingUtilities#getRootPane

Comment: SwingUtilities.getRoot(popup).invalidate(); has no effect

Comment: Popup is heavyweight container and have to call pack (derived window from SwingUtilities) after any changes

Answer (score 1):

Don't provide the preferred size. It will re size automatically.

```
popup.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 80));
```